# Visual Studio Integrated terminal bash error

Tags: bash, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use the integrated terminal in VCS but it doesn't like my `bash_profile` script.

I get the following errors (Added corresponding code) -

```
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

bash: work: command not found 
alias work="cd ./blah"
```

I'm not sure exactly why it's not working in VCS but works in Iterm2 and terminal fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you set `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.osx": ["-l"]` in your settings so it will run your `bash_profile`?